# Unable to launch WDA by Appium, trying to set up real iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I am trying to make real iOS device work with appium. Xcode build is successful when building from Xcode. After adding capabilities to appium and initiating the session, getting below errors. The same set up works as expected with simulator. it successfully installs WDA on simulator but unable to install the same on real iOS device.

Xcode: 12.5 beta
Appium:1.19.1
iOS device: 14.4.2

Here are few things that I already tried:

1. Tried doing same set up with Appium 1.18 and 1.20
2. Tried doing same set up with Xcode 12
3. Tried restarting multiple times
4. Tried with adding new provisional profile
5. Tried with different iOS devices

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Please find the log below:

> ```
>   [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
>   [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1622100235427 (12:53:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
>   [XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
>   [XCUITest] xcodebuild error message:
>   [XCUITest]
>   [XCUITest] 2021-05-27 12:53:55.058 xcodebuild[10654:265249]  iPhoneConnect: 
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:
>   failed with {
>   [XCUITest]     NSLocalizedDescription = "Unable to install \"WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner\"";
>   [XCUITest]     NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402620394 \"The
>   executable was signed with invalid entitlements.\"
>   UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8008016),
>   com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(\n\t0   DTDeviceKitBase             
>   0x000000011a2703b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220\n\t1
>   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a2aeae1
>   __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 155\n\t2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010bf1c13c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71\n\t3   DTDeviceKitBase              
>   0x000000011a2ae822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1440\n\t4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000119a67ba5
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.296
>   + 3534\n\t5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c04ec3d __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7\n\t6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c050867 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191\n\t7
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d2603
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12\n\t8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d37e6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8\n\t9
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d95ca
>   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606\n\t10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204da08d _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366\n\t11
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204e3bed
>   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811\n\t12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2067a4c0 _pthread_wqthread + 314\n\t13
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20679493 start_wqthread
>   + 15\n), DVTRadarComponentKey=487925, NSLocalizedDescription=The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.}";
>   [XCUITest] }
>   [XCUITest] 2021-05-27 12:53:55.316 xcodebuild[10654:265247]  iPhoneConnect:  failed to install
>   /Users/delcy.gandhi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-alwvnomvwrdtzoaxbbkniqrpcdpp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app
>   - error Error Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402620394 "Unable to install "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner""
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to install
>   "WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner", NSUnderlyingError=0x7fac2b6764f0 {Error
>   Domain=com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code=-402620394 "The
>   executable was signed with invalid entitlements."
>   UserInfo={MobileDeviceErrorCode=(0xE8008016),
>   com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace=(
>   [XCUITest] 0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a2703b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
>   [XCUITest] 1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a2aeae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
>   + 155
>   [XCUITest] 2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010bf1c13c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
>   [XCUITest] 3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a2ae822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken
>   installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] +
>   1440
>   [XCUITest] 4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000119a67ba5
>   __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.296
>   + 3534
>   [XCUITest] 5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c04ec3d __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
>   [XCUITest] 6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010c050867 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
>   [XCUITest] 7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d2603 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
>   [XCUITest] 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d37e6 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>   [XCUITest] 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204d95ca _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
>   [XCUITest] 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204da08d _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
>   [XCUITest] 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204e3bed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
>   [XCUITest] 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2067a4c0 _pthread_wqthread + 314
>   [XCUITest] 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff20679493 start_wqthread + 15
>   [XCUITest] ), DVTRadarComponentKey=487925, NSLocalizedDescription=The executable was signed with invalid
>   entitlements.}}}
> ```